# Ler bytes de cores (RGB) de um bitmap

Tags: c, bitmap, stream-de-arquivos

Eu estou tento um problema com um código que eu fiz que deveria exibir os bytes referentes aos valores de cor RGB de cada pixel de uma imagem no formato bmp (bitmap).

Eu sei que na api do windows tem como trabalhar com bitmaps de forma mais prática, mas como eu pretendo que o código final seja portável em questão de sistema operacional, eu criei os structs e estou fazendo a leitura apenas com o básico do C.

O código é esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char *readBMP(char *filename, int *size) {
    int width, height;
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned char info[54];

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
        return 0;

    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, file); // read the 54-byte header

    // extract image height and width from header
    width = *(int *) &info[18];
    height = *(int *) &info[22];

    *size = 3 * width * height;
    data = (unsigned char *) malloc(*size * sizeof(unsigned char)); // allocate 3 bytes per pixel
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), (size_t) *size, file); // read the rest of the data at once

    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i += 3) {
        unsigned char tmp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[i + 2];
        data[i + 2] = tmp;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return data;
}

int main() {
    int size = 0;
    char filename[] = "output.bmp";
    unsigned char *data = readBMP(filename, &size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d. %d\n", i + 1, (int) data[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }

    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

O código RGB desses pixeis são:

```
(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255),
(0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255),
(255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 255);
```

A imagem que estou tentando "ler" é um bitmap de 2x3 pixeis: https://prnt.sc/gnygch

E a minha saída é:

```
1. 255
2. 0
3. 0

4. 255
5. 0
6. 255

7. 0
8. 0
9. 0

10. 255
11. 0
12. 255

13. 0
14. 0
15. 255

16. 0
17. 0
18. 0
```

As primeiras leituras até coincidem com os pixeis de baixo, mas as outras não correspondem as outros pixels, ao menos não na ordem que ele estão dispostos.

Será que alguém consegue enxergar o que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: O link que vc postou  **não é** um _bitmap_

Comment: Eu tirei um print porquê eu tentei upar, mas ele era convertido pra png e ficava muito pequeno. Eu dei zoom e tirei print.

Comment: O problema é que não tem como testar o seu programa, uma vez que não se tem o bitmap original

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro defina sua própria estrutura para o bitmap:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h> // Para usar int32_t etc

// Usamos pragma pack push/pop serve para evitar que o windows re-escreva uint8_t para int32_t ou int64_t por motivos de eficiencia
// Acho que no linux você pode remover isso mas não testei.
#pragma pack(push,1)

typedef struct {
    uint8_t signature[2]; // Must be "BM"
    uint32_t filesize;
    uint32_t reserved;
    uint32_t fileoffset_to_pixelarray;
    uint32_t dibheadersize;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t bitsperpixel;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t imagesize;
    uint32_t ypixelpermeter;
    uint32_t xpixelpermeter;
    uint32_t numcolorspallette;
    uint32_t mostimpcolor;
} bitmap_header_t;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Depois basta abrir o arquivo e ler os pedaços:

```c
int main() {
    // Abre o arquivo de forma binaria
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.bmp", "rb");

    // Aloca um espaço para guardar o cabeçalho
    bitmap_header_t * bitmap_header  = (bitmap_header_t*) calloc(1, sizeof(bitmap_header_t));

    // Le o header do arquivo na estrutura alocada
    fread(bitmap_header, 1, sizeof(bitmap_header_t), fp);

    // Verifica se o que você leu é um BMP pela assinatura:
    if (bitmap_header->signature[0] != 'B' || bitmap_header->signature[1] != 'M') {
        fclose(fp);
        free(bitmap_header);
        printf("O arquivo selecionado não é valido: \"%s\"", fileName);
        return 1;
    }

    // Printa alguns detalhes da imagem
    int32_t size = bitmap_header->imagesize;
    int32_t width = bitmap_header->width;
    int32_t height = bitmap_header->height;
    printf("O buffer de pixeis tem %d bytes e a imagem tem %d de largura e %d de altura\n", size, width, height);

    // Aloca um espaço para guardar os dados dos pixeis
    uint8_t * buffer = (uint8_t *) calloc(size, sizeof(uint8_t));

    // Le os dados de pixel da imagem (estao na ordem BGR e nao RGB)
    fread(buffer, 1, size, fp);

    // Printa o valor de alguns pixeis
    printf("A cor do ultimo pixel em baixo a direita eh r: %d, g: %d, b: %d\n", buffer[2], buffer[1], buffer[0]);
    printf("A cor do pixel do lado esquerdo dele eh r: %d, g: %d, b: %d\n", buffer[2+3], buffer[1+3], buffer[0+3]);
    
    // Limpa os buffers alocados e o arquivo
    free(buffer);
    free(bitmap_header);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

O bmp de 24 bits (3 bytes por pixel) estão de traz para frente: começam na direita em baixo e vão para a esquerda, e estão em BGR em vez de RGB. Além disso existe um tal de padding que você vai ter que evitar para ler os pixeis em alguns cenarios.

Para entender melhor o formato use este link do wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format